# How can I list the available video modes for my screen?

Tags: video

On Windows computers, there is a simple "hide the modes this screen does not support" button.

How can I get the **available video modes** supported (accepted) by my actually connected **screen** via Linux **command line**?
I.e: I would like to answer to this question: "Would my 1280x1024 video mode be supported by this screen"

I have read about the [hwinfo](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Hwinfo) program, but it seems not to be included on Ubuntu anymore.

The other method I tested uses [vbetool](https://www.google.es/search?q=vbetool&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=A0DaVcTVOcS5aY2On4AD), but I think it is not the appropriate way:

```
luis@Terminus:~$ sudo vbetool vbemode get
16673
```

And I have read too about a method implying the **commands execution on GRUB** menu (like `vbeinfo`), but I would like to find some inside-Linux way.

Answers **generic** for any Linux distro are preferred.
If not possible, Ubuntu or Kali are accepted.

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried "xrandr" ?

> When run without any option, xrandr shows the names of different outputs available on the system (LVDS, VGA-0, etc.) and resolutions available on each

Demo output :*

```
$ xrandr -d :0  
Screen 0: minimum 64 x 64, current 1920 x 975, maximum 16384 x 16384  
VGA-0 connected primary 1920x975+0+0 0mm x 0mm  
   1920x975       60.0*+  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x1050      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   640x480        60.0
```

*Note that you can specify which X display to print info about (-d, --display), as I've done here because I ran the command over SSH (without any X-forwarding).
There does need to be at least one X display for xrandr to be of any use.

For more info, check out "man xrandr".

Comment: Upvoted. But please don't post screenshots of textual output, paste the *actual text*...

Comment: Well, I like it, but it requires X-Windows. Or so I think when yielding `Can't open display`. Upvoted anyway, as long as it solves the problem, and works even with multiscreen (two screens in my case).

Comment: @jasonwryan Sorry, I was running it in a VM so it was easier to take a snapshot than to SSH in, (where the command needs additional options). Updated now !

Comment: Mmm... but I think you still need some X display running. If I log out from Xfce and run (via TTY or remote SSH) `xrandr -d :0`, I get `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCan't open display :0`. It seems some user must be logged to the X Windows system for `xrandr` to work.

Comment: How do I interpret from that output what the name of the mode actually is (for use with --mode)? When I try to use any of the resolutions as mode names I get a “cannot find mode AxB” error, where AxB is the listed resolution.

Comment: @Kvass Have you examined the manual ? `man xrandr`. `--mode 1920x1080` for resolution, `--output HDMI-1` to specify which monitor to affect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `hwinfo`

```
sudo hwinfo --framebuffer
```

It will list all supported video modes for your terminal.

Comment: When I run that command I get no output. (No errors either, exit status 0)

Comment: Using `hwinfo v21.70` it seems you need to provide the option `--log`.  For example: `hwinfo --log framebuffer.log --framebuffer`.  Then you'll be able to view the output in the file "framebuffer.log".